# ¿Qué error existe en mi programa de traducción de notación infija a postfija?

Tags: java

tengo un código sencillo que me permite pasar de notación infija a notación postfija, únicamente con operandos de una cifra y sólo con la suma y resta, funciona en modo consola pero al pasarlo a interfaz gráfica simplemente no hace nada, le mando la cadena de entrada como string y en una clase la trabajo como una cola de char, sin embargo, la salida no imprime nada, es como si la cola no llevase los valores a los otros métodos, el código de la clase donde todo se hace es este:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Postfijo {

    static int preanálisis;
    private Queue<Character> entrada = new LinkedList<>();
    static String salida1;
    static String salida2;
    static String salida3;
    
    public void Analizador(String s) {

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            entrada.add(s.charAt(i));
            this.entrada=entrada;            
        }
        
    }


    public void expr() throws IOException {
        term();
        while (true) {
            if (preanálisis == '+') {
                coincidir('+');
                term();
                salida1=salida1+String.valueOf('+');
                
            } else if (preanálisis == '-') {
                coincidir('-');
                term();
                salida1=salida1+String.valueOf('-');
                
            } else {
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    public void term() throws IOException {
        
        for(char elemento:entrada){
        if (Character.isDigit((char) elemento)) {
            salida1=String.valueOf((char)elemento);
            System.out.println("term "+salida1);
            coincidir(elemento);
            
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la sintaxis");
            throw new Error("Error de sintaxis");
            
        }
        }
    }

    public void coincidir(int t) throws IOException {
        if (preanálisis == t) {
            preanálisis = entrada.poll();

            if(!entrada.isEmpty()){
                preanálisis = entrada.peek();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la sintaxis");
            throw new Error("Error de sintaxis");
        }

    }

}
```

Y el código para modo consola es este:

```
import java.io.*;

class Analizador{
    static int preanálisis;

    public Analizador() throws IOException {
        preanálisis = System.in.read();
        
    }

    void expr() throws IOException {
        term();
        while (true) {
            if (preanálisis == '+') {
                coincidir('+');
                term();
                System.out.write('+');
                
            } 
            else if (preanálisis == '-') {
                coincidir('-');
                term();
                System.out.write('-');
                
            }
            else return;
            
        }
    }


    void term() throws IOException {
        if (Character.isDigit((char) preanálisis)) {
            System.out.write((char) preanálisis);
            coincidir(preanálisis);
            
        } 
        else throw new Error("Error de sintaxis");
        
    }

    void coincidir(int t) throws IOException {
        if (preanálisis == t) {
            preanálisis = System.in.read();
            
        }
        else throw new Error("Error de sintaxis");
        
    }
    
}
    
    public class Postfijo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            Analizador analizar = new Analizador();
            analizar.expr();
            System.out.write('\n');
        }
    }
```

Cabe recalcar que debo basarme en este código sólo que aplicado una interfaz gráfica y manejo de errores, pueden ayduarme??